# JQuery: Enter key deletes everything after caret and doesn't render line break in views

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i'm currently using this script to create a linebreak in text fields.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea').keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart)+"\n";
    }
  });
});
```

So in the textfield i'm facing one problem. Which is if i were to have typed out something, shift the caret to before and hit enter, the new line appears but all the words behind it are deleted.

(Example if caret were | << here then everything else after it disappears when enter is pressed)

The next issue is that although the lines are broken up and displayed very nicely in the text field, when the form is submitted and rendered, there are no line breaks.

I have read a few of the other SO threads and they suggest using `<br />` instead but that just creates the `<br />` physically in my text field.

Heres the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buwr1qo2/). Do pardon me if i may not have done it correctly, as i am rather new to javascript/jquery and am not familiar with the practices when sharing code through jsfiddle.

How can i not have everything after the caret deleted and have the line breaks nicely rendered in the views too?

(If it matters my views/backend is rubyonrails and my browser is google chrome)

Comment: @DanielCheung added. i hope i did the jsfiddle correctly. do pardon me if it doesn't fall under the "usual" practices

Comment: Why do you need code to insert line breaks when typing Enter? The textarea doesn't do it by default?

Comment: @ConnorsFan nope previously enter was submitting the form for me. also i would like for the line breaks collected in the text field to render similarly in the views, like splitting paragraphs.

Comment: You can try with `event.stopPropagation()` instead of `event.preventDefault()`, like in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/buwr1qo2/5/ (and let the textarea control insert the line break).

Comment: @ConnorsFan wow `.stopPropagation();` works much better than `.preventDefault();` thanks. But when the information collected in the form is rendered in the view, the line breaks doesn't show though.

Comment: I don't know how you render the text in the view. I suggest that you replace new lines with HTML line breaks when you insert the text in the view. Something like: `viewCtl.innerHTML = txtCtl.value.replace("\n", "<br/>")`.

Comment: no worries. you've been a great help! i'll see if i can find the solution. thank you